# Connecting to TFS with NetworkCredential results in TF30063: You are not authorized to access

Tags: c#

I used the the following piece of code to connect TFS.

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("tfsserver", new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password"));
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

But I am getting the following error:

> "TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://tfs-la01q:8080/tfs."

The username and password which I used was valid. I also have rights to the TFS server.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

I would expect you to need a domain credential, unless it's a local instance of TFS Basic on your client development machine.  If you are using:

```
new NetworkCredential(@"domain\username", "password")
```

try changing it to:

```
new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")
```